# Resolving missing dependency libexif.so.9 while trying to Yum install Mono on CentOS 5.3.3

Tags: mono, dependencies, yum, centos5

I'm trying to install Mono on CentOS 5.3.3 through Yum.

According to the instructions I found elsewhere I grabbed a copy of **mono.repo** from the Mono site and placed it in the /etc/yum.repos.d directory.

The file looks like this:

```
[mono]
name=Mono for rhel-4-i386 (stable)
baseurl=http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/rhel-4-i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Next I ran **yum install mono-complete** and here's the log.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * updates: mirrors.usc.edu
 * centosplus: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * addons: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * extras: mirrors.usc.edu
base                                                                                                                                   | 1.1 kB     00:00
updates                                                                                                                                |  951 B     00:00
centosplus                                                                                                                             |  951 B     00:00
addons                                                                                                                                 |  951 B     00:00
extras                                                                                                                                 | 1.1 kB     00:00
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Reducing CentOS-5 - Extras to included packages only
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mono-complete.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: mono-nunit = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-extras = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data-firebird = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: bytefx-data-mysql = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-locale-extras = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data-oracle = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data-sybase = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-winforms = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data-sqlite = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-jscript = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-web = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-data-postgresql = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-devel = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: ibm-data-db2 = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Processing Dependency: mono-core = 1.9.1-2.novell for package: mono-complete
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mono-web.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-data.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-data-firebird.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-core.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libgdiplus0 for package: mono-core
---> Package mono-nunit.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-devel.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glib2-devel for package: mono-devel
---> Package mono-data-sybase.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-data-postgresql.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-jscript.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-data-sqlite.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package bytefx-data-mysql.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-data-oracle.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package ibm-data-db2.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-locale-extras.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-extras.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
---> Package mono-winforms.i586 0:1.9.1-2.novell set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libgdiplus0.i386 0:1.9-1.rhel4.novell set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libXrender.so.1 for package: libgdiplus0
--> Processing Dependency: libungif.so.4 for package: libgdiplus0
--> Processing Dependency: libexif.so.9 for package: libgdiplus0
---> Package glib2-devel.i386 0:2.12.3-4.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXrender.i386 0:0.9.1-3.1 set to be updated
---> Package libgdiplus0.i386 0:1.9-1.rhel4.novell set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libexif.so.9 for package: libgdiplus0
---> Package giflib.i386 0:4.1.3-7.1.el5_3.1 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
libgdiplus0-1.9-1.rhel4.novell.i386 from mono has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libexif.so.9 is needed by package libgdiplus0-1.9-1.rhel4.novell.i386 (mono)
Error: Missing Dependency: libexif.so.9 is needed by package libgdiplus0-1.9-1.rhel4.novell.i386 (mono)
```

According to [**this post on the CentOS forums**](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?viewmode=flat&topic_id=11944&forum=38), I even enabled the **centosplus** repo - but no avail.

Can anyone guide me in resolving this missing dependency of **libexif.so.9** ? I cannot seem to find the rpm for this exact version...

Thanks,
m^e

Comment: I think this belongs on serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:
I just realized that you are using CentOS 4 sources but trying to install on CentOS 5. That was almost certainly your problem. Anyway, I leave my original answer below for the benefit of all.**

I agree that this is a ServerFault thing:

> yum install libexif

or

> yum install exif

More importantly, I would definitely compile Mono from source myself so that you can use something newer. It is a breeze (once you get libgdiplus installed especially). I have done it many times on CentOS 5 and a few times on CentOS 4.

http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/sources/

Compile libgdiplus to support System.Drawing:

```
$ tar xzf libgdiplus-2.10.tar.gz
$ cd libgdiplus-2.10
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Then compile Mono itself:

```
$ tar xzf mono-2.10.tar.gz
$ cd mono-2.10
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

Comment: Thanks man. Solved at last. Compilation works like a charm minus all the dependency hiccups.